# Ansible: lineinfile syntax error when there is a space after colon(:)

Tags: ansible

Ansible's `lineinfile` gives a syntax error when there's a space after colon(:) in the line, like `line='item: value'`. If there's no space like `line='item:value'`, it works fine.

My Ansible version is 1.9.3, and here's an example.

```
- name: set up sudo for testgroup
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/sudoers line='%testgroup ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -r now' state=present insertafter=EOF validate='visudo -cf %s'
```

This task is trying to modify `/etc/sudoers`, and get the following error.

```
ERROR: Syntax Error while loading YAML script, /path/to/roles/testrole/tasks/main.yml
Note: The error may actually appear before this position: line 6, column 63

- name: set up sudo for testgroup
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/sudoers line='%testgroup ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -r now' state=present insertafter=EOF validate='visudo -cf %s'
                                                          ^
This one looks easy to fix.  There seems to be an extra unquoted colon in the line
and this is confusing the parser. It was only expecting to find one free
colon. The solution is just add some quotes around the colon, or quote the
entire line after the first colon.

For instance, if the original line was:

    copy: src=file.txt dest=/path/filename:with_colon.txt

It can be written as:

    copy: src=file.txt dest='/path/filename:with_colon.txt'

Or:

    copy: 'src=file.txt dest=/path/filename:with_colon.txt'
```

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the colon as `{{ ":" }}`:

```
- name: set up sudo for testgroup
  lineinfile: dest=/etc/sudoers line='%testgroup ALL= NOPASSWD{{ ":" }} /sbin/shutdown -r now' state=present insertafter=EOF validate='visudo -cf %s'
```

Answer (score 0):

I got another suggestion at Ansible's [github issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12380#issuecomment-140821554), which is actually suggested in the error message...

```
lineinfile: "dest=/etc/sudoers line='%testgroup ALL= NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -r now' state=present insertafter=EOF validate='visudo -cf %s'"
```

And also, aonther thing that's worth sharing is that I was suggested to stop by one of the two mailing lists, as appropriate:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ansible-project - for user questions, tips, and tricks
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ansible-devel - for strategy, future planning, and questions about writing code